AGV picking multiple boxes out of a rack system
I am currently working on a project with automatic robots (AGVs) and a rack system. Now I'm struggling with the "rack storage" block and can't figure out the problem. I want an AGV to pick several boxes from the rack and then move them to an unloading zone.
If anyone is familiar with this and would like to help me, I would be very grateful.
The rack system is filled with the boxes very fast at the beginningFilling the rack system.
I already tried using the batch block, but that didn't do what I wanted.
I would like an AGV to drive to 3 cells in the pallet system one after the other and load a box at each place and then unload these 3 boxes in one zone.

Use the Batch block before pickup. This batches your containers into a generic batched agent that you can pickup as 1 entity

Hi, thanks for the answer. I had already tried that, the problem is that I can no longer use the rack pick block because my new batch agent is not in the warehouse. Is there also a solution that the 3 boxes are batched into one and that the AGV then moves to a position in the rack and collects all three at once? Or is there another solution? Thanks in advance.

Pls always mention what you already tried. You need to setup a loop around the pickup block and manually define which containers to load, in this case

Okay. I will open a new question with more details.
